# JPA Group by with multiple field

Tags: jpa, group-by, openjpa, named-query

I am getting following error while using named query blog.findBlogs

"Your select and having clauses must only include aggregates or values that also appear in your grouping clause."

In select clause I have used b.id so it must allow to perform this query without error. I also tried same query from mysql workbench and its working perfectly fine.

```
@NamedQueries( value = {
        @NamedQuery (name = "blog.findBlogs", query = "SELECT " + 
                            "NEW com.vo.Blog(b.id, b.blogId, b.createDate, b.tags, b.url, COUNT(r.emotion)) " +
                            "FROM Blog b JOIN b.rates r " + 
                            "GROUP BY b.id")
})
```

regards, Amit J.

Answer (score 0):

In general, a `GROUP BY` query in SQL must obey a rule that everything which appears in the `SELECT` clause must either appear in the `GROUP BY` clause or be inside an aggregate function, such as `COUNT`.

> I also tried same query from mysql workbench and its working perfectly fine.

It turns out that MySQL is one of a few databases which does not enforce this rule.  But JPA appears to not allow this, so it fails for you running from JPA even though the underlying database is a lax version of MySQL.

Here is how you can modify your code to run without error:

```
@NamedQueries( value = {
    @NamedQuery (name = "blog.findBlogs", query = "SELECT " + 
                        "NEW com.vo.Blog(b.id, COUNT(r.emotion)) " +
                        "FROM Blog b JOIN b.rates r " + 
                        "GROUP BY b.id")
})
```

If you're wondering what the logical problem with your original query was, it is that, for a given `b.id` value, JPA cannot figure out *which* blog, date, and tags value to choose for that group.

Comment: thanks for your response.

In select clause I am interested in other fields as well as long with Id.

Comment: What you are asking makes no sense.  _Which_ other values do you want?  You need to provide logic for determining which value you retain for each id group.

Comment: Its look like group by should be changed to 
    b.id, b.blogId, b.createDate, b.tags, b.url
instead of only 
    b.id
Basically I want to populate blog VO along with its rating from Rate entity. Blog can be rate by multiple user

Comment: Not necessarily.  If you this, the count may not be what you intend.

Comment: Can you suggest how can I achieve it. I have two entity classes Blog and Rate with one-to-many relationship (One blog can be rated multiple times with different users). I want to pull say for e.g. 10 blogs but while populating Blog's VO I am also interested to get the aggregated values from Rate table (like average rating, total likes/dislikes etc.) for each blogs.

Comment: @AmitJain You should start by writing the actual SQL query you would need to get your answer.  Then figure out how to modify your JPA query to achieve it.